# Faketime lib on Mac not always works

Tags: osx, date, brew

Installed libfaketime with brew, latest version 0.9.7, then did following steps as described in README.OSX:

```
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/Cellar/libfaketime/0.9.7_1/lib/faketime/libfaketime.1.dylib
export FAKETIME="2000-01-01 01:01:01"

/Applications/Appname.app/Contents/MacOS/Appname
```

Sometimes it's uses Faketime, but mostly it uses my system's actual date. How can i dig in to this issue?